# Rationale behind specialized methods in iostream library for binary data

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand **why** the iostream library has specialized `read()` and `write()` methods for handing binary data.  Why does the operator overloading of `ifstream` and `ofstream` classes not handle binary data transparently, once a file has been opened in the binary mode (`ios_base::binary`)?

I have tried to look for a satisfactory answer but I am not finding one.

Comment: Only the C++ committee can answer WHY, but think about it - how do you expect the `>>` and `<<` operators to behave differently for binary data? Where do you expect them to stop reading/writing? Can you provide an example? The operators are for **formatted** data, and binary data is **unformatted** data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is absolutely an issue with extraction but perhaps insertion could be managed.  Anyway, great answer.

Comment: There is a similar feature in the C language.  You have `fwrite` and `fread` for writing to a `FILE *`, regardless of the mode of the file.  You should ask the C language committee as to why.

Comment: Let's suppose there are two definitions at play here.  The `ios::binary` *mode* say that there will be no translations to and from the file.  For example, MSDOS likes to translate 0x1A as an end of file marker.  Opening the file as binary eliminates this translation.  The `write` and `read` methods aren't binary, but **block** operations.  They write blocks of memory to the file or read files to memory.  Separate concepts here.  The mode controls translations of the data to and from the file.  The `write` and `read` transfer blocks of data.

Comment: Even for insertions it would be a problem. How is the library to tell the difference between a formatted and unformatted insertion. Also, recall that character insertions go through the locale system, which you definitely do not want a binary blob to experience. Having overloads for these kinds of operations makes all sorts of sense.

Comment: What makes you think `read`/`write` handle binary data differently? For example, the only difference between `some_ostream.write(s, std::strlen(s));` and `some_ostream << s;` is that the first won't set the failbit if writing a character fails

Comment: No one knows if `int` should be written big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: All programming languages (or libraries) that I'm aware of, if they support both formatted and unformatted I/O, do so in a comparable manner (i.e.  the file needs to be opened in relevant mode, distinct methods to read/write in each case, and mixing things [e.g. opening in binary, writing formatted] is either undefined/unspecified or causes a runtime error).

Comment: I write text into binary files using formatted output all of the time to avoid line ending translation for compatibility with other platforms. If `<<` did something different for binary files I'd be out of luck.